# mysql group by part of queried entry

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

My (simplified) query

```
SELECT name, city FROM some.tbl WHERE name LIKE "%clarendon%" ORDER BY city, name
```

I get something like below:

```
name                            city
Budget Lodge Clarendon          Clarendon
Clarendon Artillery Lane        London
Clarendon Barbican Studios      London
Clarendon Brushfield St         London
Clarendon Canary Central        London
Clarendon Commercial St         London
Clarendon Cottages              Sassafras
Clarendon Discovery Dock East   London
Clarendon Gooch House           London
Clarendon House And Gardens     Kew
Clarendon Luxury Apartments     Edinburgh
Clarendon Manning Place         Richmond
Clarendon Minories              London
Clarendon Motel                 North Conway
Clarendon Pepys St              London
Clarendon Puma Court            London
Clarendon Steward St            London
Clarendon Vine St               London
Clarendon Wellington St         London
Clarendon Wraysbury             Staines
Hotel Clarendon                 Quebec
The Clarendon                   London
The Clarendon Bantry Bay        Cape Town
The Clarendon Fresnaye          Cape Town
The Clarendon Hotel             Newcastle
```

What I would like to get is this -

col.name keeps its order, but col.city gets ordered by col.name fragment enging with word clarendon:

```
name    city
  Budget Lodge Clarendon          Clarendon
  Clarendon Luxury Apartments     Edinburgh
  Clarendon House And Gardens     Kew
  Clarendon Artillery Lane        London
  Clarendon Barbican Studios      London
  Clarendon Brushfield St         London
  Clarendon Canary Central        London
  Clarendon Commercial St         London
  Clarendon Discovery Dock East   London
  Clarendon Gooch House           London
  Clarendon Minories              London
  Clarendon Pepys St              London
  Clarendon Puma Court            London
  Clarendon Steward St            London
  Clarendon Vine St               London
  Clarendon Wellington St         London
  Clarendon Motel                 North Conway
  Clarendon Manning Place         Richmond
  Clarendon Cottages              Sassafras
  Clarendon Wraysbury             Staines
  Hotel Clarendon                 Quebec
  The Clarendon Bantry Bay        Cape Town
  The Clarendon Fresnaye          Cape Town
  The Clarendon                   London
  The Clarendon Hotel             Newcastle
```

**EDIT**
Typo - of course it is "ORDER BY name, city "
but question still remains valis

Comment: It seems you are currenlt using `ORDER BY name, city` and not `ORDER BY city, name`

Comment: name - city switch will not hold name order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is incorrect. The query you posted would already give you the second results.

[edit]

```
ORDER BY
  substr(name, 1, 9), city, name
```

Comment: it will not - I have result right here in front of me; when you look closer at second sample, col.name gets sorted by "%clarendon[stop]" - then col.city gets sorted within sort results of col.name

Comment: True. What about the order by I added?

Answer (score 0):

The first result you have seems to be using `ORDER BY name, city` and not (as you claim) `ORDER BY city, name`.

The second result can be returned by:

```
SELECT name, city 
FROM some.tbl 
WHERE name LIKE "%clarendon%" 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, 'Clarendon', 1)
       , city
       , name ;
```

Comment: this is still not cutting, but looks promising as a base

Comment: sorry - slang - should not have used it - it does not work - I am not getting expected results

Comment: It should return what you want with the sample you posted. The problem  may be because `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` does a case-sensitive search while you have both `clarendon` and `Clarendon` in the data.

Answer (score -1):

This query simple query accommodate your need:

```
SELECT name, city 
FROM some.tbl 
WHERE name LIKE "%clarendon%" 
ORDER BY name ASC, city ASC
```

Comment: Right. it just show explicit order. it's order by name and the by city, not 'order by city, name'.

Comment: name-city switch will not do - col.name will get messed up - see my example

Comment: I think on your first query result, it just order by name, not by 'city, name' as mentioned on your question. And for your expected result must be ordered by 'name, city'. I think you miss here. Try retest your query.

Comment: yes - there was a problem with query order mix up, however anyway you do ordering it does not work - see expected example - col.name is ordered by "%clarendon[stop]" and then by city within col.name result